# Hibernate ManyToMany relationship with additional columns

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I want to have ManyToMany relationship between two tables with a join table, which has an extra column. I followed [this tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany), but still getting errors. I am using Spring MVC with Hibernate
Here are my entities: There are Questionblocks and Questions, and an Association between them.
Question:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Question")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int ID;

    String title;
    String description;
    String Type;
    String defaultValue;
    boolean deleted;
    boolean isDraft;
    boolean visible;
    Timestamp modifiedDate;
    String modifiedBy;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock> questionBlocks;

    //GETTERS, SETTERS, CONSTRUCTORS...

    }
```

QuestionBlock:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Questionblock")
public class QuestionBlock {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int ID;

    String title;
    String description;
    boolean deleted;
    boolean isDraft;
    boolean visible;
    Timestamp modifiedDate;
    String modifiedBy;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="questionBlock")
    private Set<AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock> questions;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="questionBlocks")
    Set<Survey> surveys;

    public void addQuestion(Question q, int pos){
        AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock association = new AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock();
        association.setQuestion(q);
        association.setQuestionBlock(this);
        association.setQuestionID(q.getID());
        association.setQuestionBlockID(this.getID());
        association.setPosition(pos);


        if(this.questions==null){
            Set<AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock> questionBlocks = new HashSet<>();
            questionBlocks.add(association);
            this.questions=questionBlocks;

        }else{
            this.questions.add(association);
        }

        if(q.getQuestionBlocks()==null){
            Set<AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock> questionBlocks = new HashSet<>();
            questionBlocks.add(association);
            q.setQuestionBlocks(questionBlocks);
        }else{
            q.getQuestionBlocks().add(association);
        }


    }
    }
```

Association

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QuestionBlock_Question")
@IdClass(AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlockID.class)
public class AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock {

    @Id
    private long QuestionBlockID;
    @Id
    private long QuestionID;

    int Position;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "QuestionBlockID", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private QuestionBlock questionBlock;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "QuestionID", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Question question;


}
```

AssociationID:

```
public class AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlockID implements Serializable {

    private long QuestionID;
    private long QuestionBlockID;

    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (QuestionID + QuestionBlockID);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (object instanceof AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlockID) {
            AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlockID otherId = (AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlockID) object;
            return (otherId.QuestionID == this.QuestionID)
                    && (otherId.QuestionBlockID == this.QuestionBlockID);
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TestingController {

    SurveyService surveyService;


    @RequestMapping("test")
    public String test(Model model) {

        Question q = surveyService.getQuestion(7);

        QuestionBlock qb = new QuestionBlock("tesztblokk", "ee", "czadam");

        qb.addQuestion(q,1);
            surveyService.save(qb);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

After that, when I try to call the Controller method, nothing gets inserted in the join table (). (Only in the questionblock table)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set up cascading of the persist operation from `QuestionBlock` to `AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock`.

Cascading will make sure that when persisting the `QuestionBlock` entity, the freshly created and associated `AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock` entities (that are in transient state) get persisted as well.

```
public class QuestionBlock {

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="questionBlock", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock> questions;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this design, which I would not advise, you'll have to add mapping annotations to the fields of `AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlockID`, remove the insertable and updatable attributes from your ManyToOne associations, and add a `MapsId` annotation to these associations.

But the good, simple, more efficient, easier way is to treat the `AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock` entity as all the other entities, and to use an auto-generated, single-column ID for this entity. If you want to make sure that you don't have more than one instance with the same questionID-questionBlockId, then use a unique key constraint.

BTW: why do you use `int` for the ID of your entities, and `long` to reference them in `AssociationQuestionToQuestionBlock`?